# Left() function in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want a very handy way to extract the numbers out of a string in Javascript and I am thinking about using jQuery, but I prefer the method that proves to be the simplest. I have requested the "left" attribute of a css block using jQuery like this:

```
var stuff = $('#block').css("left")
```

The result of "stuff" is

```
1008px
```

I just want to get rid of the "px" because I need to do a parseInt of it. What is the best method? If Javascript had a left() function, this would be very simple. Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just do a `parseInt("1008px", 10)`, it will ignore the 'px' for you.

Comment: parseInt(stuff,10); //Don't forget the radix

Answer (score 29):

To answer your other question, you can add a `left()` function to JavaScript's built-in `String` `prototype` class so all other strings will inherit it:

```
String.prototype.left = function(n) {
    return this.substring(0, n);
}
```

And once you include this you can say:

```
var num = "1008px".left(4);
```

I add helpers like `trim` and `capitalize` in a base JavaScript file for these kinds of things.

Comment: fwiw, the native substr() is equivalent to left(), but I'm all for adding cheap flexibility

Comment: @annakata: substr() has not been standardized by ECMAScript and is thus deprecated. And still, you'd need to specify the start and length, but you are right, left() is just a convenience.

Comment: There also is slice (15.5.4.13)

Answer (score 10):

$('#block').offset().left contains the actual left position value as an integer.

Comment: That actually returns a different value - it returns the left position of the element relative to the document, not the css value for left set to the element.

Comment: Besides, "jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the body element. While it is possible to get the coordinates of elements with visibility:hidden set, display:none is excluded from the rendering tree and thus has a position that is undefined." (http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Answer (score 3):

Left() is of almost no use here, as you'd first have to calculate the offset. You could, however, use a regular expression, to either pull out the number, or delete illegal characters:

```
var value = "1080px";
var num = value.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
// or
var num = value.replace(/\D+/g, '');
// or
var num = value.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

That is, in case parseInt() isn't enough for you... :)

Comment: Using `parseInt()` on any string with letters in it (along with the number you're seeking) gives `NaN`, just FYI.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to  have that number without **'px'** try it:

`$('#block').position().left`

That would be simplest on JQuery )

Answer (score 2):

```
parseInt(stuff, 10);
```

edited to use the radix comment.

> parseInt(stuff,10); //Don't forget the radix – some Jan 29 '09 at 11:32

Comment: parseInt(stuff,10); //Don't forget the radix

Comment: Using `parseInt()` on any string with letters in it (along with the number you're seeking) gives `NaN`.

Comment: Whoa this question is 12 years old!  Are you sure using `parseInt` on a string with letters always gives `NaN`?  https://jsfiddle.net/mgb84k3h/

Comment: @JohnBoker Running your fiddle, even after adding a semi-colon after your alert, doesn't give an alert, so not sure about that - but when I did a `console.log(parseInt("1024px"));` I got the desired `1024` output. But if I did `console.log(parseInt("country1"));` - I get `NaN` instead of `1`. I thought maybe it only worked for `px` values, but I did `console.log(parseInt("1024asd"));` and got `1024` as expected. It's weird that it will work in some instances, but not others, so I wanted to call attention to that.

Comment: It looks like when the number part is at the beginning of the string it works.