# Get left, right values with out px in jquery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Left() function in Javascript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490508/left-function-in-javascript-or-jquery)

I have one div and i give style like below.

```
#MainDiv
{
    position:relative;    
    left:150px;
    right:150px;

}
```

I want to give the width of this `#MainDiv` based on the left and right parameters. For this I give like below.

```
$("#MainDiv").width($("#MainDiv").width() - $("#MainDiv").css("left") - $("#MainDiv").css("right"));
```

But  `$("#MainDiv").css("left")` is giving me `150px` in the alert. I want only the `150`. For that I used `offset` property, `$("#MainDiv").offset().left` and `$("#MainDiv").offset().right`. The left value is coming as `158` and right is coming as `undefined`. `offset` is not correct at this situation? How should I remove that `px` at the end of the value and get the exact value?

Comment: @All.. this question may duplicate of that one.. but the number ways we can achieve shown here are more than that question. Thanks to all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

do:

```
var left = parseInt($("#MainDiv").css("left"), 10);
```

Comment: In case anyone wonders, the 10 is for "base 10" or radii, which apparently is not always assumed in javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Try using jQuery [**position()**](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

```
 $(element).position().top;
 $(element).position().left;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parseInt( $("#MainDiv").css("left").replace('px', '') );
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
$("#MainDiv").css("left").slice(0, -2);
$("#MainDiv").css("right").slice(0, -2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the px. Your script is wrong. This should help you out-

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pxWnY/1/)

```
<div id="MainDiv"></div>
```

CSS

```
#MainDiv
{
    position:relative;    
    left:60px;
    right:50px;
    border:1px solid;
    height:10px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#MainDiv").width(parseInt($("#MainDiv").css("left")) - parseInt($("#MainDiv").css("right")));
});
```